# IntelliJ OpenFL Haxe run configuration fails with two empty error messages

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe, openfl

Building from IntelliJ IDEA is giving me two empty error messages.  Neither error message provides any description of the error, just an empty message stating: `Error:`

[image: intellij-errors]

However, the build appears to be successful.  If I target Flash, under `Export/flash/bin` the SWF file exists and runs perfectly.  It's like the return code from the compiler is being incorrectly interpreted as an error.

Regardless of build target or project, it appears to be an issue with the plugin to IntelliJ.

Projects compile without issue and run great via the command line.

Environment:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.0.1
- Haxe toolkit 3.1.3
- Haxe support custom language Plugin 0.8.1 updated August 21, 2014

Project:

[image: intellij-project]

Module:

[image: intellij-module]

Run configuration:

[image: intellij-run-configuration]

Comment: I have the same problem with Intellij IDEA 13.1

Comment: Both [JetBrains](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-haxe) and [TiVo](https://github.com/TiVo/intellij-haxe/) plugins have issues in IntelliJ 13 and 14.  Issues are stacking up in [TiVo's GitHub issue](https://github.com/TiVo/intellij-haxe/issues) - there's a branch under development that will hopefully resolve issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue where the plugin had not yet been updated to support IntelliJ IDEA 14.

IntelliJ IDEA 14 support has now been added, and installing a current version of the plugin no longer has this issue.